# SOLR 7.1 Extracthandler extract PDF WILL ADD Many extra META data which i don't want,it don't happen in solr 6

Tags: pdf, solr, extract

1.SOLR 7 extract pdf
will add many schema column(pdf meta)
and  extra meta  pdf data

2.in solr 6,it don't happen

4.how can i close it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're running with a "schemaless" update processor in 7, so that any unknown fields are added to the schema by the update processor. If you turn that off and use an explicit schema like you probably did in 6, you should see the old behavior again.

You might need to switch to the [ClassicIndexSchemaFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html#SchemaFactoryDefinitioninSolrConfig-SwitchingfromManagedSchematoManuallyEditedschema.xml) to get Solr to read your old schema.xml.

> 1. Rename the managed-schema file to schema.xml.
> 2. Modify solrconfig.xml to replace the schemaFactory class.
> 3. Remove any ManagedIndexSchemaFactory definition if it exists.
> 4. Add a ClassicIndexSchemaFactory definition as shown above
> 5. Reload the core(s).